# Reading from a file and sorting alphabetically

Tags: c++, sorting, alphabetical

I am in a fundamentals C++ college course and I am completely stuck on one of my assignments.

I need to read the input from a file that has a list of (1-25) names, sort the names alphabetically, and then output which people would be at the front of the line (ex:Amy) and the back of the line (ex:Zora). My professor is very particular and he strictly forbids us from using anything we haven't learned in class. We have only learned, cin, cout, if statements, loops, basic operators, fstream and basic string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Intialize variables
    string studentName;
    string firstEntry;
    string secondEntry;
    string first;
    string last;
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;
    int students;

    //Ask for amount of students
    cout << "Please enter the number of students in the class.\n(The number must be a whole number between 1 and 25.)\n";
    cin >> students;

    //Input validation
    while (students < 1 || students > 25)
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid value. Please enter a value between 1 and 25.\n";
        cin >> students;
    }

    //Get file name from user
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file with the list of students\n";
    cin >> filename;

    //Open the file
    inputFile.open(filename);
    if (inputFile)
    {
        while (inputFile >> studentName)
        {
            cin >> studentName;
            studentName = firstEntry;
            cin >> studentName;
            studentName = secondEntry;

            if (firstEntry < secondEntry)
            {
                firstEntry = first;
                secondEntry = last;
            }
        }
        cout << first << " is the first student in line.";
        cout << last << " is the last student in line.";
    }

    else
    {
    cout << "Error opening the file.\nPlease restart the program and try again.";
    return 1;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Also here is the file I am reading from:

Jackie

Sam

Tom

Bill

Mary

Paul

Zev

Barb

I'm mainly stuck on the reading from the file and interpreting the data part.

Comment: So how are we supposed to know what you've learned in class i.e. what is allowed or not?  You better list every lesson you've had so far so we don't give you advice you haven't learned yet.

Comment: It would be difficult to advice you without knowing the topics that you have learned. Since it is assignment, use your skills to solve the problem in hand. There are many ways to solve a problem..but if you do it yourself. then it would be helpful for you to understand the basic programming constructs.

Comment: If you only need the first and last, you don't need to worry about sorting the whole list. A similar problem would be returning the min and max in a list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. You should carefully consider your variable types and usage. Since you choose to use `std::string`, you should get familiar with its basics from [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).
2. Thoughtful variable naming can help you avoid some obvious programming bugs. For instance, you use

   ```
   cin >> studentName;
   ```

   which should clearly be the string `studentName1` and not the int.
3. Plan out your usage of variables. Do you really need all the ints? You are sorting the names themselves alphabetically, not numbers.
4. Use assignments carefully.

   ```
   studentName = firstEntry;
   ```

   indicates you are assigning the value of `firstEntry`, i.e. 0 to `studentName`, effectively replacing anything it was meant to contain before.
5. For the actual sorting, you have a choice to make between available `std::string` functions, or if that's prohibited in your class constraints, classic string iteration. In case of the latter, the biggest lead would be the fact that a string can be iterated as a character array. Sorting then simply reduces to character comparison.
6. Last tip, which judging from your attempt, you probably had in mind already. Since you only need to output the first and last names in the queue, you need not sort the entire list, just maintain the first and last names.

Good luck!

Comment: I edited the code to reflect your suggestions,  however, whenever it gets to the point where it reads the file, the code stops. I am sure the file is in the correct place because I have tested it with cout. Also we are only allowed to use the base string function. We havent learned anything in that link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need max and mi just compare the strings and store in 2 separate variables

set the first name as min initially then traverse the entire file

compare with the initial name

if it is less replace else store in max

compare max with the incoming text if greater replace

correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ask your professor to teach you about `std::set` and `std::getline` then you can let the power of C++ work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("names.txt"); ///< open input file
    if (!input.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::set<std::string> sortedNames; ///< set is sorted by default!
    std::string name;
    while (std::getline(input, name)) ///< get every name in file line by line
    {
        sortedNames.insert(name); ///< insert name into sorted set
    }

    for (const auto& n : sortedNames) ///< print sorted names
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: If you're not interested in the full sorted set of names and you just care about the first and last entries, you can simply set up iterators to those elements in your set and just dereference them to get their values.

```
 auto iter = sortedNames.begin();   ///< iterator at first element
 auto riter = sortedNames.rbegin(); ///< iterator at last element
 std::cout << "The first student is: " << *iter << std::endl;
 std::cout << "The last student is: " << *riter << std::endl;
```